# How can i export MS Sql Server Database dump and Import that Into Mysql Database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am in a strange situation now, I am very new to MS Sql server Database think. Am working on mysql now. I have a databse in MS Sql server database and i want to create a same database in mysql. I try to generate script from MS Sql server into a file dump.sql now that i need is i cannot use that file to import into mysql database.

Can some one tell me how can i use the generated script to create a database in mysql?

Or is there any other way i cano directly get mysql formate script from MS Sql server ?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one page where i can use the script from ms sql generated scripted which give mysql Script.

http://www.burrist.co.uk/mstomy.php

Answer (score 0):

- Create the table in MySQL manually (using the CREATE TABLE from SQL Server as a *template*)
- Export the data as CSV from SQL Server
- Import the data into MySQL from the CSV

Comment: It does not work for me. I cannot directly import, an exported CSV file from ms SQL into mysql. Thank you for the help